# two conditions within my FirstOrDefault with one being dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-core

My code is crashing on this line but it seems to be written correctly.
error im seeing in my terminal: `error CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation`

my controller:

```
public IActionResult Remove(int ParticipantId)
{
MMLeagueParticipant removeThisParticipant = db.ParticipatingKids.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ParticipantId == ParticipantId && i.sport.sport == ViewBag.SportsTab);
}
```

league model:

```
    public int LeagueId { get; set; }

    public string sport { get; set; }

    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string ageRange { get; set; }
    public List<MMLeagueParticipant> allParticipants { get; set; }
```

MMLeagueParticipant model:

this is my middle table that has many to many relationship between the League Participant Models

```
    public int MMLeagueParticipantId { get; set; }
    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }
    public int LeagueId { get; set; }

    public League sport { get; set; }
    public ViewModel.Participant child { get; set; }
```

**What I tried:**

I removed the second part of the FirstOrDefult and the error went away; however, I still need to do a check on the sport. When I tried running it with only the second part half of the FirstOrDefault  the error came back.

I checked if I was receiving the correct information by adding a line of code to my controller to see if I was getting the correct information and I was.

```
Console.WriteLine("remove ParticipantId:"+ParticipantId+" here for "+ViewBag.SportsTab);
```

this leads my to believe it doesnt like `i.sport.sport`

Comment: ViewBag is a dynamic type.  You can't use it in an expression tree.  Instead, pull the value of the ViewBag prop out, cast it to a non-dynamic type, and use that variable in your expression.

Comment: Try writing it like this `MMLeagueParticipant removeThisParticipant = db.ParticipatingKids.Where(i=>i.ParticipantId == ParticipantId && i.sport.sport == ViewBag.SportsTab).FirstOrDefault();` and see what happens